# Spring mvc include one single 'form' for different c:url

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring-mvc application. In the application, there are various types of events, for which the user can register. As for registration, there is a standard formula with details like firstName, email, address, etc. I am just giving different c:url values depending which event it is. 
I was wondering if it is possible to include the form(not the c:url part) in another jsp file, and just call jsp:include. This would serve me very well as when the form needs to be styled, updated, etc, then I need to update only one file. I am including how the form looks. Kindly have a look. Thank

eventregistration.jsp :

```
  <c:url var="addAction" value="/student/add/seminar-e-commerce" ></c:url>
            <form:form class="seminar-form" action="${addAction}" commandName="students">
                <table>
                    <form:hidden path="studentid"/>
                    <label>Firstname/LastName <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                    <form:input path="firstname" type="text" class="span6 border-radius-none" />
                    <span>   </span>
                    <form:input path="lastname" type="text" class="span6 border-radius-none pull-right" />

                    <label>Email-Address <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                    <form:input path="emailadress" type="text" class="span12 border-radius-none" />


                    <label>Street Name/Number <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                    <form:input path="address1" type="text" class="span10 border-radius-none" />
                    <span> </span>
                    <form:input path="address2" type="text" class="span2 border-radius-none pull-right" />


                    <label>City/PLZ <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                    <form:input path="city" type="text" class="span10 border-radius-none" />
                    <span> </span>
                    <form:input path="plz" type="text" value="" class="span2 border-radius-none pull-right" />

                    <label>Handy Number <span class="color-red"></span></label>
                    <form:input path="handynumber" type="text" value="" class="span12 border-radius-none" />

                    <label path="newsletterpermission">Want to subscribe newsletter?</label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="newsletterpermission" class="form-control" value="true"/>Yes
                    <form:radiobutton style="margin-left:15px" path="newsletterpermission" class="form-control" value="false"/>No
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <c:if test="${empty students.firstname}">
                        <input class="btn-u" type="submit"
                               value="<spring:message text="Register for event"/>" />
                    </c:if>
                </table>
            </form:form>
```

Any pointers would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an entrypoint/method in your controller with a Pathvarible of action like below

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/student/{action}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String EntryPoint(@PathVaribale String action, ModelMap model) {
             switch (action) {
             case "add":
                  // delegate to addMethod
                 break;
             case "activate":
                   // delegate to activateMethod
                 break;
             case "register":
                // delegate to registerMethod
                 break;
             default: 
              ///Unsurported operation
       }

            return "index";
        }
```

and you can keep the c:url , remember to set up the model.action attribute on a controller method responsible for setting up the form bean, for your case students bean or make it more general

```
 <c:url var="action" value="/student/model.action/" ></c:url>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This part I am aware of. I am asking about the form part which is below c:url. Can I refer to <form:form from other JSP file?

Comment: Yes you can by including or go the ajax route by repainting the DOM

Comment: So can I put the form only in 1 jsp file and use include tag?